# glGetUniformLocation using a lot of CPU

Tags: opengl

Is it normal that when I call `glGetUniformLocation` in my render loop only once, the CPU usage of the process goes up to 30-40% ? Should I only call this method once and store the location in memory?

Here's my code:

```
GLuint Shader::getUniform(const std::string &name) const
{
    return glGetUniformLocation(m_programId, name.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I see nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: How much is the CPU usage without the `glGetUniformLocation` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I only call this method once and store the location in memory?

Yes, that would be the ordinary procedure. Either that, or using [fixed locations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29#Explicit_uniform_location).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal that when I call `glGetUniformLocation` in my render loop only once, the CPU usage of the process goes up to 30-40% ?

It is normal that doing this wastes CPU cycles, but the impact this has on your overall performance is going to depend on the host CPU and the complexity of your scene.

It seems you are fairly GPU-bound if something this simple increases your CPU load by that much. In a way, that is a good thing, it suggests you are using the *rest* of the OpenGL API efficiently.

> Should I only call this method once and store the location in memory?

You need to understand that the location only changes when you link your program. Even if the driver uses an optimized data structure like a trie to accelerate this search, it is still going to be a massive waste of CPU cycles to repeatedly perform a search for something that does not change.

*"Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results."   - Albert Einstein*

Typically people will enumerate the active uniform locations after a program is linked and store them persistently. In newer versions of GLSL (4.30 or using [`GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/explicit_uniform_location.txt)), you can explicitly assign uniforms locations using `layout (location = N) uniform ...` and avoid having to query anything at all.